# Passing initialized object to setState React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

I'm implementing chat functionality on a website. On submitting the message, the new message is added to an array storing all chat messages sent during the session.

```
<form
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    id="chatForm"
    className="chat-form border-top"
  >
    <input
      value={state.fieldValue}
      ref={chatField}
      type="text"
      className="chat-field"
      id="chatField"
      placeholder="Type a message…"
      autoComplete="off"
      onChange={handleFieldChange}
    />
  </form>
```

I also have a useEffect that monitors the change in the chatMessages array and prints out the current state + scrolls the chat window to the bottom.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(state);
  chatLog.current.scrollTop = chatLog.current.scrollHeight;
}, [state.chatMessages]);
```

The first way I'm doing this is as follows:

```
const newState = { ...state };

newState.chatMessages.push({
  message: state.fieldValue,
  username: appState.user.username,
  avatar: appState.user.avatar,
});
newState.fieldValue = "";

setState(newState);
```

This results in the following:
[state change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWIXm.png)

The console.log is printed from the initial render, but it is never printed again. However, new messages are displayed, giving me the indication that some state update has worked and chat messages have been added to the array.

The second way I've updated state is passing the object literal directly to the setState function:

```
setState({
  ...state,
  chatMessages: [
    ...state.chatMessages,
    {
      message: state.fieldValue,
      username: appState.user.username,
      avatar: appState.user.avatar,
    },
  ],
  fieldValue: "",
});
```

This results in the expected behavior: [state change 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dH7i.png)

In this state update, the console.log prints out the correct state after every update.

My question is why react's state update behaves this way. I understand the mutability of changing state directly, but why is the first method of updating state add my messages to the queue, but not register with the useEffects listening for changes?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Yeah, the first version is incorrect because you're mutating state which is unpredictable. There's no guarantee it won't accidentally work or won't partially work, but it's basically off-limits and probably not terribly useful to reason about the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is not registering with `useEffect` because you're manipulating state directly vs. using the state setter. You technically can make changes to the state item directly when using `useState` (assuming you don't have strict linting), but it's wildly unreliable and a liability if used in a real application.

You may also want to consider useReducer, which is reccomeneded by the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer):

> Another option is useReducer, which is more suited for managing state objects that contain multiple sub-values.